# Debug printing unpacking variadic template function arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I am trying to create a general debug print function.

```
enum class DebugLevel : uint8_t
{
    INFO     = 0,
    EVENT    = 1,
    WARNING  = 2,
    ERROR    = 3,
    CRITICAL = 4
};

DebugLevel generalDebugLevel = DebugLevel::INFO;

template <typename ...T>
void DPRINT (DebugLevel dbgLevel, T&& ...args)
{
    if (dbgLevel >= generalDebugLevel)
    {
       std::cerr << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " " << args... << std::endl;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I need to unpack as I pass it to <<.

Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

```
template <typename ...T>
void DPRINT (DebugLevel dbgLevel, T&& ...args)
{
    if (dbgLevel >= generalDebugLevel)
    {
       std::cerr << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " ";
       using expander = int[];
       (void)expander{0, (void(std::cerr << std::forward<T>(args) << " "),0)...};
       std::cerr << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does [using expander = int[]] do?

Comment: This: "DPRINT(DebugLevel::INFO, "Error Occurred [" << errno << "].");" does not compile.

Comment: @Oscar_Mariani why should `"Error Occurred [" << errno << "]."` as a function argument compile? It's not a macro that substitues parts of the function's body with given *text*

Comment: You are absolutely right... sorry, I was using a #define before. Thanks!

Comment: @Oscar_Mariani and regarding your first question, `expander` introduces an alias for `int[]`, since `int[]{0}` is not a valid syntax